# Proof of the identity of a Boolean equation $Y+X'Z+XY' = X+Y+Z$

Tags: boolean-algebra

How to prove the following the identity of a Boolean equation?

> $$ Y+X'Z+XY'=X+Y+Z $$

---

I have tried :

$
\space\space\space\space\space 
 Y+X'Z+XY'\\
=X'Z+XY'+Y\\
=X'Z+XY'+Y(X+X')\\
=X'Z+XY'+XY+X'Y\\
=X'(Z+Y)+X(Y'+Y)\\
=X'(Z+Y)+X‧1\\
=X'(Z+Y)+X\\
$

Then, how to continue?

**Thank you for your help.**

Comment: Use $A+BC=(A+B)(A+C)$

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma
How is (A+B)(A+C) = A+BC? LHS is A+AB+AC+BC.

Comment: @tpb261: $A+AB+AC=A$

Comment: @user2357112 Ah.. yes.. stupid me :(

Answer (score 2):

$$Y+X'Z+XY'$$
$$=(Y+Y')(Y+X)+X'Z$$
$$=1.(Y+X)+X'Z$$
$$=(X+X')(X+Z)+Y$$
$$=1.(X+Z)+Y$$
$$=X+Y+Z$$

Hence, proven.

Comment: See, how better it looks now! Latex is simple. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Logically,

- Y+X'Z+XY' is true whenever Y is true, irrespective of X and Z.

  Removing all inputs where Y is false, X'Z+XY' is true, when X is True (we know Y is false), irrespective of Z.

  And finally, when both X and Y are false, X'Z is true, hence the expression is true.

```
In all three cases, we were only concerned whether one parameter was true or 
not, the others were either false or not affecting the result, so, it is same 
as Y+X+Z.
Or you could expand Y=Y(X'Z'+X'Z+XZ+XZ') and then repeat some terms from this 
expansion and group them with the other terms.
```